# How do I create HTML emails on Mac?

Tags: email, pages, html

I'd like to know the best way to create gorgeous mail templates such as Jumsfot's [Stationary Mail ones](http://www.jumsoft.com/stationery/) and send them without having to use Safari.
Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this once, when Apple discontinued the iCards, but I wasn't able to do anything that looked nearly as good.

There is a tutorial here: [The Graphic Mac](http://www.thegraphicmac.com/how-to-create-customized-os-x-mail-stationery-in-snow-leopard)

The full documentation is available at [Apple's developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/MailArticles/Articles/stationery.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006068-SW1).

Comment: Tks iPacheco, I already tried the GrapgicMac method but I wasn't satisfied with the results. The process is too long. I will pay attention to Apple's developer site. Thanks