# Is there an app that lets you code and send HTML e-mail from your Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, email

Apple Mail doesn’t seem to let you edit the source of HTML e-mails ([customised stationery workarounds](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7716/how-to-create-html-emails-on-mac) aside).

Is there a Mac app that lets you send HTML e-mails?

A bit of Googling turned up [HTMLMailer](http://www.epacketware.com/software/htmlmailer/), but it looks like it’s no longer available.

Comment: ..are you aware that you can send the content of any HTML-website by pressing cmd+i in Safari? This way you could generate documents just like you would any other HTML and then send them as e-Mails.

Comment: @Asmus: sure, that’s a decent way to do it. Pop that in as an answer and receive the upvotes you deserve.

Comment: Sending from Safari doesn't always work. Sometimes even if you choose the Web Page option in Mail, it only sends text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Entourage [sort of supported this](http://www.templatekit.com/tstore/article.php?art_id=44), I don't know if its replacement (MS Outlook) still does. Either way, you'd need MS Office to use it, which probably isn't what you want.

[This article](http://bytes.com/topic/macosx/insights/825931-quick-way-send-html-emails-apple-mail-mail-app) also suggests a way to achieve something similar to it with Mail.app and Safari, but I haven't tried it to see how well it works.

Comment: I *think* it does, so it a good option to know about.

Answer (score 12):

You can code and design your Mails as HTML(+CSS) documents, open them in Safari.app and then press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to have the content automatically transferred into Mail.app

Keep in mind that not all CSS-styles are supported by all Mail-clients, a good overview on that can be found [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: “Keep in mind that not all CSS-styles are supported by all Mail-clients” — sure, although from Mail you can send the e-mail, and then potentially look at it in different clients.

Answer (score 4):

[Direct Mail](http://directmailmac.com) will do what you're looking for. You can edit the HTML source code of your message by hand, or use the WYSIWYG editor to manipulate your message. Works with Apple Mail stationery, too.

When you send the message, Direct Mail will also automatically inline your CSS and apply some tweaks so it renders properly in Gmail, Hotmail, and other "HTML-challenged" email clients.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for Direct Mail.

Comment: Good stuff, cheers for the additional info about Direct Mail. Looks good.

Answer (score 3):

I had some difficulty using the CMD + I method from Safari however you can also:

1. Open your html file in safari
2. CMD + A (select all)
3. CMD + C (copy)
4. Compose a new message in the Mail app
5. CMD + V (paste) in the body of the new message

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called Direct Mail that has both a "lite" and "pro" versions. http://ethreesoftware.com/directmail/

Answer (score 2):

I routinely use [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) for this purpose.

You can use the menu item Insert > HTML to either insert a blob of HTML or edit the entire source of your message (CMD + A, Insert > HTML)