# Sending HTML mails (without a 3rd party app)

Tags: macos, email, html

I've been trying to send an html mail with images embedded.

Same as you would do if you embedded items into your stationary folder in outlook.

I don't want to use a 3rd party app...because i need to send this to a client and then they will forward to a whole bunch of people...so i can't send it via a 3rd party app because once you do, if you try forward it then all the images and formatting etc don't come with the mail.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this answer in another thread: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9759/16258

Comment: @Mark: OP specifically asks how to accomplish this without installing another app.

Comment: However forwarding does not remove images etc as such so there is another issue here

Answer (score 5):

You can do this relatively simple from the command line. Save your HTML, but also include the necessary SMTP headers at the top in the source. For this example I'll save the source as `example.html` in my home directory.

**~/example.html:**

```
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Test email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can send this e-mail from Terminal.app by executing the following command:

`cat ~/example.html | sendmail -t`

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be HTML? I find that PDFs are best for such things. Take your HTML, load it in a browser, and save as a PDF using the free Paparazzi, which can save a web page as a single PDF, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Thanks Kirk...well they need the content to go into the body of the email...because its a email newsletter, so im assuming you'd have to attach the pdf? Which wouldn't really help.

Comment: Yes, the PDF would be an attachment. I've worked on HTML email newsletters, and they very hard to get right across clients, especially if it's across platforms as well. If it's a repeated thing, you might want to check out MailChimp, which has lots of templates.